# How to execute Mustache template with JSON/String on Android?

Tags: java, android, json, string, mustache

I have `String` object with template base, something like:

```
<h1>{{header}}</h1>
{{#bug}}
{{/bug}}

{{#items}}
  {{#first}}
    <li><strong>{{name}}</strong></li>
  {{/first}}
  {{#link}}
    <li><a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a></li>
  {{/link}}
{{/items}}

{{#empty}}
  <p>The list is empty.</p>
{{/empty}}
```

I want to pull another `String` object representing `JSONObject` and put its fields into template:

```
{
  "header": "Colors",
  "items": [
      {"name": "red", "first": true, "url": "#Red"},
      {"name": "green", "link": true, "url": "#Green"},
      {"name": "blue", "link": true, "url": "#Blue"}
  ],
  "empty": false
}
```

In the end I would get `String` representing HTML structure:

```
<h1>Colors</h1>
<li><strong>red</strong></li>
<li><a href="#Green">green</a></li>
<li><a href="#Blue">blue</a></li>
```

I don't want to use any POJOs or `Map`s - only use standard `String` objects or alternatively convert second `String` into `JSONObject` to use it as a template's context. 
Could someone give me any example how to achieve that? 
Thanks.

**Edit**: I don't know anything about template/`JSON` structure while executing template - I have to play with unknown template/`JSON` and assume that they are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find way to work on pure `String` objects - I am converting `JSONObject` to `Map` to get it working with Mustache. This is code for conversion:

```
public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException
{
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
    Iterator keys = object.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext())
    {
        String key = (String) keys.next();
        map.put(key, fromJson(object.get(key)));
    }
    return map;
}

public static List toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException
{
    List list = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
    {
        list.add(fromJson(array.get(i)));
    }
    return list;
}

private static Object fromJson(Object json) throws JSONException
{
    if (json instanceof JSONObject)
    {
        return toMap((JSONObject) json);
    } else if (json instanceof JSONArray)
    {
        return toList((JSONArray) json);
    } else
    {
        return json;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
mustacheTemplate.execute(JSONUtils.toMap(new JSONObject(myString)));
```

Comment: One last question how do you get the html from the template and your json data  ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am getting your question correctly, but 'execute' method returns formatted HTML String which you can use inside WebView.

Comment: i want to get the formatted html string but i don't understand where mustacheTemplate.execute() come from. Can you explained it to me on chat please ?

Comment: Sure, pop in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26632/how-to-execute-mustache-template-with-json-string-on-android  :)